# Dúvida sobre termos controle versão TFS

Tags: terminologia, visual-studio-2015, versionamento, team-foundation-server, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Estou aprendendo versionamento, minha dúvida é com relação aos termos mostrados na figura abaixo `Epic` e `Issue`, procurando a tradução dos mesmos pra mim não fez sentido quanto utilizar estas opções para criar um `Work Item`

[image: Foto]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo [documento da Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/scaled-agile-framework-visual-studio-online-process-template-updates/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), **Epic** é um item geral que está acima de *features*. É uma definição geral de um problema, é algo que transcende um *release* ou interação de projeto. É um [conceito usado pela metodologia Agile](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/userStory.htm#Epics).

**Issue** é um [impedimento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ff731580(v=vs.110)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para o andamento do projeto. Não é um erro, mas é algo que precisa ser resolvido para o projeto estar correto. A resolução passa por uma investigação. O resultado dessa investigação pode gerar um relato de *bug* ou outra ação necessária, ou pode ser dispensado como algo não relevante e constar só como histórico.

Isso normalmente é [usado na metodologia CMMI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb668962(v=pandp.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177334/101).

Answer (score 1):

Os Work Items não são para gestão de código fonte e sim para a gestão de requisitos.

O Team Foundation Server (TFS) é uma ferramenta bem completa de ALM, ele não é somente um versionador de código fonte, mas também inclui módulo de gestão de requisitos, de build, de deploy, etc... Todos eles estão sob uma plataforma, que é o que o TFS acaba sendo, ao invés de várias ferramentas atendendo as diversas disciplinas de ALM, uma única e com administração e gestão de segurança integrada, portanto facilitando na administração.

Por ser entregado, os Work Items podem ser relacionados a checkin de um código, caso esteja usando o TFVC, ou commit, caso use Git. E com isso você tem o histórico de código relacionado com os requisitos.

Um Work Item é a abstração de requisitos, então ele pode ser do tipo Issue ou Epic, cada um com a sua função dentro do desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, realmente este `Work item` que mostrei na figura estava sendo relacionado a um `caso de uso`. No `Work item`eu vou detalhar o caso de uso que posteriormente será implementado. @egomesbrandao