# Diferença entre epics e features

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, requisitos

No Visual Studio Team Services é possível organizar o *backlog* em *epics*, *features* e *user stories*.

Para cada epic, um conjunto de *features* associado pode ser definido, e para cada *feature* um conjunto de *user stories* associado pode ser definido.

O que eu não entendi ainda é a diferença entre *epics* e *features*. Pelo que eu pesquisei "*epic* é um requisito muito grande, que precisa ser dividido em *user stories*", mas não entendo a diferença disso e de *features*.

Alias, mesmo essa definição de *epic* é subjetiva, porque afinal, como eu sei que algo é grande o suficiente para ser um *epic*?

Dessa forma, o que realmente são *epics*, o que realmente são *features* e qual a real diferença entre ambos?

Alguns exemplos que eu vi em um video na internet:

- Epic: Mobile strategy

  - Feature: Mobile favoriting
- Epic: Continuous improvement

  - Feature: Botify the wordoo service
  - Feature: Improve performance

Comment: Questão não adequadamente marcada como *projeto-de-software*. Remover esta marca facilitará a localização de questões pelos usuários.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou te explicar como você entende no código, ainda que não tenha uma relação direta entre os termos:

Pense em *epic* como o *namespace*, em *feature* como a classe, e em *story* como método. Porque em cada desenvolvimento tem um módulo que possui objetos que possui comportamentos.

Reforço que não há um relação direta entre eles, é provável que tenha uma granularidade diferente quando vai colocar em código.

Então ***epic***  é uma descrição geral do que se deseja do software. Não há muitos detalhes e recomenda-se manter dentro apenas uma interação. É uma forma de organizar (agrupar) muitas *features*. Um exemplo é gerenciar produtos.

Já a ***feature*** é algo um pouco mais concreto do que terá, tem um pouco de detalhes do que é aquilo, sua função. Em caso dela ser complexa também deve manter dentro de uma interação de desenvolvimento. Como exemplo podemos citar inserir a engenharia do produto ou a venda do produto.

As ***stories*** dizem o que deve ser feito, quais as operações que o usuário fará em cima daquela *feature*. Exemplos podem ser: vendedor emite pedido de venda, financeiro aprova venda, estoquista separa produtos, despachante emite nota fiscal.

Obviamente que uma estória pode usar uma característica dentro dela, assim como características podem ter outras características. Eventualmente uma característica não precisa ter estórias. A epopeia é interessante em sistemas mais complexos. É incomum mas uma estória pode não fazer parte de uma característica.

Então *epic* não tem a ver com tamanho e sim com grandeza, que são coisas diferentes. *Epic* está em um nível acima de sumarização. É como se fosse um país. Existem países menores que estados e municípios, por isso o tamanho não interessa, mas a abrangência dele sim.

Tudo isto faz parte da análise de requisitos. Se fizer errado, e todo mundo faz, o desenvolvimento se complica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que entendi melhor, a ideia seria ir a cada nível detalhando mais o que o sistema precisa, sendo que quando quebramos um epic em features estamos dando mais detalhes do requisito, mas ainda não indo muito a fundo, e o mesmo com stories, porém aí sim sendo bem específico sobre cada requisito? De qualquer jeito, existe alguma relação de algum desses itens da hierarquia com casos de uso? Me pareceu que os casos de uso seriam documentados por feature, mas pelos seus exemplos de stories eu fiquei meio em dúvida.

Comment: @Leonardo Basicamente é isto, Não que precise manter uma hierarquia certinha, como eu disse na resposta. Use case de fato é muito próximo de feature, mas ela é feita de uma forma um pouco diferente. A verdade é que tem que ser compreensível, tem que atender a sua necessidade como desenvolvedor ou da sua equipe. É bom não inventar muito para manter a boa comunicação com outras pessoas, até aquelas que você não sabe que mexerá no sistema no futuro, mas não precisa seguir regrinha rígida.

Answer (score 3):

Epic, Features e User Stories são artefatos do SCRUM, e não definições do VSTS.

Esses artefatos o ajudam a quebrar os valores de suas entregas em blocos de espectativas.

Em um exemplo muito simples, um sistema simples de loja:

- Epic 1: Logistica

  - Feature 1: Itens do estoque

    - Story 1: Como usuario resposavel pelo estoque, desejo lista itens que estão no estoque;
    - Story 2: Como agente de recepcao de pacote, desejo poder informar que novo produtos chegaram no estoque
  - Feature 2: Notas Fiscais

    - Story 1: Como usuario da contabilidade, desejo lançar NFs no sistema;
- Epic 2: Loja Online

  - Feature 1: Vitrine

    - Story 1: Como cliente, desejo filtrar por produtos em promoção
    - Story 2: Como cliente, desejo adicionar um item ao carrinho de compras
  - Feature 2: Emitir ordem de compras

    - Story 1: Como cliente, desejo criar uma ordem de compra
- Epic 2: Finanças

  - Feature 1: Auditoria em ordens de compra

Assim pode-se quebrar seu projeto em tamanho de valores de entrega.

Voce pode ver mais no [Guis do SCRUM em Português Brasileiro](http://www.scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2016/2016-Scrum-Guide-Portuguese-Brazilian.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Depende muito de alguns conceitos próprios. No geral, Epic é algo mais abstrato, trata-se de um conceito global e sem muita definição do seu software. Já a feature trata-se de algo mais concreto e especifico, eu vejo uma feature como um serviço que atende a necessidade do usuário.

Answer (score -1):

Epics e Features são tipos de Work Item.

Você deve utilizá-los para quebrar o trabalho afim de ver a evolução de um projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para maiores informações, ler o link da documentação oficial do Azure Devops:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=azure-devops